# Java web service client cdata tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-ws, jdeveloper

Is it possible in simple way to send string inside cdata tag witout escaping chacters?
I used @XmlCDATA tag for this String and it changes its value to  when I use Marshaller. But when I want to send Request to SoapUI it'doesn't add this. When I add this tag manually (for example in setter) it escapes characters.

For Example:
If i use marshaller I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getRequest xmlns="pl/nosd/Get">
    <ClientNumber>
        <![CDATA[<CLIENT_NUMBER>]]>
    </ClientNumber>
</getRequest>
```

And that's correct.

But when I want to send this to soapui using service:

```
sync_Customer_Service = new Sync_Customer_Service();
Customer_PortType customer_PortType = sync_Customer_Service.getCustomer_HTTPSPort();
GetRequest  getRequest = new GetRequest();
getRequest.setClientNumber("<CLIENT_NUMBER>");
customer_PortType.get(getRequest);
```

i get:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetRequestMessage xmlns="pl/nosd/Get" xmlns:ns2="http://pl/nosd/Get/xsd">
         <ClientNumber>&lt;CLIENT_NUMBER></ClientNumber>
      </ns2:GetRequestMessage>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I added jaxb.properties file with:    javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

and I added @XMLCdata annotation to GetRequest class:

```
public class GetRequest {
    @XmlCDATA
    @XmlElement(name = "ClientNumber", required = true)
    protected String clientNumber;
    public String getClientNumber() {
        return clientNumber;
    }
    public void setClientNumber(String value) {
        this.clientNumber = value;
    }
```

Service and portType classes were generated by jdeveloper by using web service proxy option.

Comment: What's the point having CDATA instead of an escaped string? These are two representations for the same data.

Comment: System, i send request to expects that form.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Workaround is not beauty, but it works. In client class I add handler:

```
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)account_PortType;
    List<Handler> handlerList = bp.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
    RequestResponseHandler reqResHelper = null;
    handlerList.add(new HeaderHandler());
    bp.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

And in handler I replace value with Cdata value:

```
    public class HeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
          private static final String SYSTEM_ID = "pl/Customer.wsdl";
          private static final String NODE_NAME = "ClientNumber";
          public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
     try{
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            Object o = context.get(LogicalMessageContext.WSDL_DESCRIPTION);
            org.xml.sax.InputSource is = (org.xml.sax.InputSource)o;
            if(is.getSystemId().contains(SYSTEM_ID)){
                SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
                SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
                Node e =getNode(body.getChildNodes());
                CDATASection cdataSection = message.getSOAPPart().createCDATASection(e.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                e.replaceChild(cdataSection, e.getFirstChild());
            }
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        //TODO logować
    } 

    return true;

}

public Node getNode(NodeList a){
    if(a!=null&&a.getLength()>0){
        for(int i = 0;i<a.getLength();i++){
            Node b = a.item(i);
            if(b.getNodeName()!=null && b.getNodeName().contains(NODE_NAME)){
                return b;
            }
            Node node = getNode(b.getChildNodes());
            if(node!=null){
                return node;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

In soapui we see:

```
<ns6:ClientNumber>
  <![CDATA[data]]>
</ns6:ClientNumber>
```